# TextFormField validation when focus changes

Tags: flutter

I am using a form and some TextFormFields.
I can validate the user input as below:

```
final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

void saveForm(){

_form.currentState.validate()

}

//saveForm runs when a save button is pressed.
```

I want to know whether it's possible to run validate function for a TextField when it loses its focus or not.(I don't want to validate the input by clicking a button and instead, I want to run validate function when user changes the TextField.)

Comment: You might take a look at [FocusNode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html), [hook it](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus) with `TextField`, and use `addListener` and `hasFocus` to listened the focus changed. Is this what you want?

Comment: the problem is that _form.currenState.validate() runs all validate functions for all the TextFormFields that have validate: (){} , I want to run validate function of one TexFormField when it doesn't have focus.

Comment: You know `_form.currenState.validate()` run all validate function, so what you want to do is to give up this method to another way... You could validate every single `TextFormField` by your own without all at once, and you want to validate data on unfocus, so I'm afraid this is the only way.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you just want to add `autovalidate: true,` in your form so when your focus is change validation is call

```
 Form(
         key: _formKey,
         autovalidate: true,
         child:/*...*/
    )
```

Create your form like

```
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autoValidate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: _autoValidate,
          child: /* ... */
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

when you click on save

```
void _onSignUpClicked(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Successfully sign up")));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: autovalidate updates when the text inside the field changes, and it triggers for all fields. It seems like the question wants to only perform the validation on a single field and only when it loses focus.

Comment: Currently, Flutter 3.0.2 does not have `autovalidate` property for the form.

Answer (score 10):

To validate a text field when focus changes from one field to the next, you need a `FocusNode` to detect when focus has been removed and a `GlobalKey<FormFieldState>` on the `TextFormField` to tell it to validate. Here is a sample:

```
class FormValidationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormValidationDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormValidationDemoState createState() => _FormValidationDemoState();
}

class _FormValidationDemoState extends State<FormValidationDemo> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  FocusNode focusNode1;
  FocusNode focusNode2;
  final field1Key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  final field2Key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode1 = FocusNode();
    focusNode2 = FocusNode();
    focusNode1.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode1.hasFocus) {
        field1Key.currentState.validate();
      }
    });
    focusNode2.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode2.hasFocus) {
        field2Key.currentState.validate();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode1.dispose();
    focusNode2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Form Demo')),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              key: field1Key,
              focusNode: focusNode1,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a value.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              key: field2Key,
              focusNode: focusNode2,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a value.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add autoValidateMode to your form

> **autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,**

```
child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      child: Column()
)
```

Auto validate has two more modes **disabled**(never auto validate) and **always**(in all cases even without any user interaction).

Read more over here

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutovalidateMode-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/autovalidateMode.html

Answer (score 6):

Put `TextEditingController` to `TextField` and use `addListener` for getting every change. And do validate process inside that listener.

Answer (score 5):

To notice, the accepted solution now is deprecated after `1.19`
Now, new parameters has been introduced `AutovalidateMode` with three essential constants:

1. always : Used to auto-validate Form and FormField even without user interaction.
2. disabled : No auto validation will occur.
3. onUserInteraction : Used to auto-validate Form and FormField only after each user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of validating the whole form using a global key, You can create a key for each of your `TextFormField()`

```
final formField1Key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
final formField2Key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
TextEditingController field1Ctr = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController field2Ctr = TextEditingController();
```

And then you can validate each of the form using

```
formField1.currentState?.validate()
```

For me i used onChange property of TextFormField()

See the sample code below

```
     Form(
          key: globalFormKey,
          // autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction, //commented this out
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: field1Ctr,
                      focusNode: FocusNode(),
                      key: field1Key,
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      onChanged: (val)=>field1Key.currentState?.validate(),
                      prefix: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/email.svg')),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null ||
                            (!isValidEmail(value,
                                isRequired: true))) {
                          return "Please enter valid email";
                        }
                        return null;
                      }
                  )),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    key: controller.pwField,
                      onChanged: (val)=> field2Key.currentState?.validate(),
                      focusNode: FocusNode(),
                      controller: field2Ctr,
                      minLines: 1,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null ||
                            (!isValidPassword(value,
                                isRequired: true))) {
                          return "Please enter valid password";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      prefix: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/svg/password.svg')))),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
                
            ],
          ),
        )
```